# Create progress bars on click, only one runs at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, promise

I found the solution in the fiddle below, but I am not sure what is happening in the click event.

```js
$(() => {
  const $container = $('#container');
  const $addButton = $('#add');
  const $progress = $('.progress');

  let promise = Promise.resolve();

  $addButton.on('click', () => {
    const $newProgress = $progress.clone();
    $container.append($newProgress);
    promise = promise.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
       $newProgress.addClass('active');
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
      }, 0);
    }));
  });

});
```

```css
#add {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.progress .bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}

.progress.active .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='add'>+ Add</button>
<div id='container'></div>

<div style='display: none'>
  <div class='progress'>
    <div class='bar'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrs9bpsn/

questions:

1. Why do we need setTimeout here? Wouldn't transition css take care of animating the progressbar?
2. Can someone please explain the promise logic here? I am not very good with promises.

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: `I found the solution in the fiddle below` --> ask the owner of the code or better, google each function and try to follow step by step

Comment: This code doesn't really make much sense - having a fixed duration animation on a progress bar would make it useless. The bar should represent the completeness of the task being undertaken.

Comment: To answer you question; The timeout is used to simulate a task that will finish at some point in the future (something asynchronous like uploading a file). The promise isn't resolved until the task is complete.

Comment: Ye, also all of this can be achieved via a animation in css

Comment: @Turnip this question was asked during an interview so there wasn't any task that the progress bar represented. Thanks for setTimeout explanation, I will lookup more in that direction.